# Combine time series data for certain rows

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

What's the most efficient way to combine time series data for certain rows?

In my case, I have time series data for four stocks in different dfs.
They all have a few columns but I am only interested in the 'Close' column.

Below is what I came up with, is this the most efficient way (new to pandas and time series)?

Cheers

```
def start(verbose: False):
    price_tsla = download_normalize_prices('TSLA', 'Tsla')
    price_aapl = download_normalize_prices('AAPL', 'Aapl')
    price_amzn = download_normalize_prices('AMZN', 'Amzn')
    price_sp500 = download_normalize_prices('^GSPC', 'SP500')

    combined_df = pd.concat([price_tsla, price_aapl, price_amzn, price_sp500], axis=1)
    combined_df.plot()
    plot.show()
    print( combined_df.head(5))

def download_normalize_prices(ticker, new_col_name):
    cols_to_drop = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Volume', 'Dividends', 'Stock Splits']
    prices = yf.Ticker(ticker).history(start='2022-1-1', end='2022-12-31')
    prices = prices.drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1)
    prices = normalize_price(prices)
    prices = prices.rename(columns={'Close': new_col_name})

    return prices


def normalize_price( price_df ):
    price_at_row_0 = price_df['Close'].iloc[0]
    return price_df.div(price_at_row_0).mul(100)
```

Comment: I'd probably change `prices = prices.drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1)` to `prices = prices[['Close']]`, but this code looks perfectly fine to me. `pd.concat()` seems like the simplest way to accomplish what you're interested in.

Comment: @NickODell Thanks Nick! I like the direct approach of picking the column I want rather than dropping the ones I don't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposition :

```
def start():
    d = {"TSLA": "Tsla", "AAPL": "Aapl", "AMZN": "Amzn", "^GSPC": "SP500"}
    prices = {ticker: download_prices(ticker) for ticker in d}
    combined_df = pd.DataFrame(prices, columns=d)
    combined_df.plot()
    print(combined_df.head(5))

def download_prices(ticker):
    prices = yf.Ticker(ticker).history(
        start="2022-01-01", end="2022-12-31")["Close"]
    return normalize_prices(prices)

def normalize_prices(prices):
    return prices.div(prices.iloc[0]).mul(100)

start()
```

Output :

```
                                 Tsla        Aapl        Amzn       SP500
Date                                                                     
2022-01-03 00:00:00-05:00  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000
2022-01-04 00:00:00-05:00   95.816730   98.730844   98.308441   99.937038
2022-01-05 00:00:00-05:00   90.693293   96.104607   96.451091   97.998983
2022-01-06 00:00:00-05:00   88.741268   94.500311   95.803809   97.904535
2022-01-07 00:00:00-05:00   85.595694   94.593707   95.393024   97.508000
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Proposition looks promising indeed.